# Combining Rasterize with ParametricPlot

Tags: graphics

The goal is to create an image like the one below

[image: Desired output]

which was created using

```
ParametricPlot[{t, t^2}, {t, 0, 1}, Epilog -> Disk[{0.5, 0.5}, 0.09]]
```

but instead of using the Graphics primitive I want to use a Rasterized version of Disk.

Using the commands below, how can I duplicate the result?

```
bkgd = Rasterize[Disk[{0, 0}, 0.09]];
pplot = ParametricPlot[{t, t^2}, {t, 0, 1}];
```

It is important that ParametricPlot remain un-Rasterized.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, you have to define `bkgd` differently because it's not a disk unless you make it a `Graphics` first:

```
bkgd = Rasterize[Graphics@Disk[{0, 0}, 0.09]];
```

Then use `Inset`:

```
ParametricPlot[{t, t^2}, {t, 0, 1}, 
Epilog -> {Inset[bkgd, {.5, .5}, Automatic, .2]}]
```

[image: Disk in plot]

The position and size of the disk image are controlled by the last three arguments of `Inset`.

You will note that the last argument (the size scale) is a factor relative to the   plot region (with `1` corresponding to the whole width).